# Please assist with partition management- cannot reformat drive to install Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, lvm

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 onto my drive, and am now trying to install Windows .  Ideally, I would like to just completely wipe the drive and remove all partitions, so I am working with a blank slate, as it will be easier to install a dual boot with Windows and then Linux.

I tried to reformat the largest partition of my drive to NTFS so I could install Windows (using gparted), but was given the message

"You are formatting over non-empty LVM2 Physical Volume /dev/sda3

Deleting or overwriting the Physical Volume is irrecoverable and will damage or destroy the volume group"

It advises me to use LVM to free physical volume before attempting to reformat.

Now here's the question: how would I safely free the volume up in LVM so that I can reformat with gparted?

Or, if the ultimate goal is to erase all partitions and format the drive for NTFS, would it be better to just forcibly reformat?  Could this cause physical damage to my drive?

Sorry for the noobery, I am in way over my head here and I don't want to wreck my drive or something.  Can give more information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not damage your drive (unless you have bad sectors).

Think of LVM as a partition that can hold other partitions. You can delete LVM the same way as you delete any partition. It's perfectly safe. I would recommend re-formatting the entire drive to NTFS, anyways.